# Polymer - Using Font Awesome icons in pager-menu-button

Tags: dart, font-awesome, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm using [that package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fontawesome_elements) with Font Awesome icons which I can use with Polymer. I want use it in `<paper-menu-button>` tag. It's possible? How Can I do that? I tried add `icon="fa-save"` parameter, but it don't works...

My code looks that:

```
      <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
        <paper-menu-button icon="fa-save" class="white" halign="left" valign="bottom">
          <core-item label="Visibility"></core-item>
          <core-item label="Extension"></core-item>
          <core-item label="Info"></core-item>
        </paper-menu-button>
      </core-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon needs to be made available using the `<core-iconset>` element to be usable with the `icon` attribute.
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-iconset

### Update

I just published the package [BWU FontAwesome IconsetSvg for core-elements and paper-elements](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg).

It works fine with your example. You can use it directly or use it as example how to create your own iconset for paper-elements and core-elements

The rendering quality (in Chrome) could be better but it seems this has been fixed http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Awesome option by Günter Zöchbauer. I took a different approach where all SVG glyphs are defined in one element file. See [Font-Awesome Polymer Iconset](https://github.com/philya/font-awesome-polymer-icons).

Of course, the file turns out to bee too big for use in production, so you might want to generate a subset using this [python script](https://github.com/philya/font-awesome-polymer-icons-generator).

Answer (score 0):

There is an element for that.

Use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontawesome-iconset:

1. get the icons you need from `fa-icons.html`
2. put it in a new `iron-iconset-svg`
3. import `iron-iconset-svg` and `iron-icon`
4. use it like other `iron-icon`

You can view how to use here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package to use FontAwesome as icons in polymer components: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_fontawesome

It's good way if you use dart-polymer-1 or don't want to use bower with polymerize.

Looks like:

```
<iron-icon icon="fa:eye"></iron-icon>
```